# How to recognise an enter character in Html

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a HtmlEditor(ajax control) in which i am giving some contents to be modified by the user on click of a button(fetched from the database).

When i fetch the contents into a textbox control the 'spaces' and 'enter' come as it is stored in database but when i use HtmlEditor 'spaces' and 'enter' doesnt come and the text is displayed as a plain paragraph.

My code is as follows:

```
 OdbcConnection casetype = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=testcase;User=root;Password=root;Option=3;");
            casetype.Open();

//*******to get order
            string ordequery = "select orde from testcase.orddetpabak where fil_no=? and orderdate=?";
            OdbcCommand ordecmd = new OdbcCommand(ordequery, casetype);
            ordecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", HiddenField4.Value);
            ordecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox3.Text);
            using (OdbcDataReader ordeMyReader = ordecmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (ordeMyReader.Read())
                {
                   String order = ordeMyReader["orde"].ToString();
                }

            }

string editorcontents= "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + order ;
 Editor1.Content = editorcontents;
```

If i simply do

```
textBox1.Text=order;
```

than everything is fine but i want the same output in HtmlEditor control. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace newline characters with `<br />` tags:

```
string editorcontents= "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + order.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

Comment: Or just `<br>` if it's HTML (and not XHTML)